# Find a>1 s.t. $a^x = x$ has a unique solution

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, simulation, newton-raphson

What $a$ makes $\{x\mid a^x = x\}$ a singleton?

$$(1.4444)^x - x \le 0 \tag 1$$ has real solutions.

$$(1.4447)^x - x \le 0 \tag 2$$ has no real solutions.

I guess $1.4444 < a < 1.4447$

I tried running simulations using goal seek in Excel, but I think I'm doing it wrong because I keep getting a lot of values below $1.4$.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: For each $a$, find the minimum value of $a^x - x$. Look at whether this minimum value is positive or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $a^x = x \iff a = x^{1/x}$.  So, there will be a solution to your problem if and only if $a$ is in the image of the function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ (over the domain $x > 0$).  Note that the graph $y = f(x)$ achieves a maximum somewhere, then levels off to its asymptote at $y = 1$.

This problem is a bit easier to solve with calculus.  In particular, it suffices to find the maximum value of $f(x)$.

Note that $f(x)$ achives its maximum iff $\ln(f(x))$ achieves its maximum.  So, we consider the function
$$
g(x) = \ln(f(x)) = \frac{\ln x}{x}
$$
We find
$$
g'(x) = \frac{1 - \ln x}{x^2}
$$
Thus, [$g$ has a unique critical point when $x = e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%27s_calculus_problem), which means that this must be where $g$ achieves its maximum.  Thus, $f$ achieves its maximum at $x = e$.

Thus, the maximum value of $a$ such that $f(x) = a$ has a solution is
$$
a = e^{1/e} \approx 1.44467
$$

Comment: Also, note that when $a = 0$, we have exactly one solution.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do we care about f's maximum? Any point of f(x) will have solutions.  $1^{1/1} = 1$ so $1^x = x$ has a solution at x = 1 and it's obviously unique.  $2^{1/2}$ so $\sqrt{2}^x = x$ has a solution at x = 2 although it isn't unique.  Any value below the y =1 asymptote will also be unique (I think).  $1/2^2 = 1/4$ so $(1/4)^x = x$ has a solution at x = 1/2 and I think this is probably unique.  I think $a = x^{1/x}; 0<x \le 1; x = e$ will have unique solutions.  (I'm too lazy to verify though.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks ^-^ Re $a=0$, clever, but I think that depends on the domains, which I failed to specify hehehe

Comment: @BLCL you should also consider $0 \leq a < 1$.

Comment: Not everyone accepts that $0^0 = 0$.  But, c'mon $1^x = x \imlies x = 1$ is clever too, isn't it.  And $.25^x = x \implies x = 1/2$ is too..

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh right. Fine. I'll edit question for a > 1. Thanks

Comment: @fleablood see link I added in answer

Comment: I didn't know that the problem had a name... interesting

Comment: Steiners problem is finding a maximum but not about finding  unique values.  Unique values occur at the maximum x =e but *also* at $0 < x \le 1$.  So $a = x^{1/x}$ for those will have unique solutions as well.  $1 < x; x \ne e$ well yeild problems with two solutions.

Comment: @fleablood yes, those values of $a$ also yield a unique solution.  I didn't think of it at first, and apparently it's not what the asker had in mind.

Comment: Well, he was honing in on pairs of solutions.  Which, as you point out, is geographically honing in on the max of f(x).  But globally and in general, we should not a continuous function g(x) will have multiple values between the the extrema and single values  "beyond" the extrema.  In this case there is a global maximum at e, and as there is an asymtote we have a range below.  It's sort of interesting (but not very) that we have both types of ranges of singletons, single values at an extreme (as, say an even powered polynomial) and a range beyond (as, say, an odd powered polynomial).