# What is the largest base whose exponential function has nonzero fixed points in the real numbers?

Tags: exponential-function, fixed-points

For a while I've been interested in functions with fixed points (if I'm correct, functions for which $f(x)=x$), and while playing around with exponential functions of the form $y =a^x$, I noticed that while $y=1.5^x$ doesn't intercept $y=x$ anywhere, $y=1.4^x$ did (at $x=1.887$ and $x=4.41$). So I started fiddling around with the base, and so far it has led me to $y=1.4445043755045700040184897261497^x$, which intercepts $y=x$ approximately at $x=2.652$ and $x=2.787$.

What I want to know is, is this approximately the largest base with nonzero fixed points? If so, is there any significance to that number, or these fixed points?

Comment: Hint:  Euler's number is e=2.7182818284590452353602874713527......

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591750/81360)

Comment: Oh, it's good to know that the question had been answered before. I suppose since I hadn't formulated the question like that, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving
$$x=a^x$$
equivalently
$$x^{1/x}=a$$
or
$$\frac{\ln x}x=\ln a.$$
So we want the maximum of $f(x)=(\ln x)/x$ over $x>1$. Now
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$
so the maximum is at $x=e$ giving
$$a=e^{1/e}.$$

Comment: Thank you! After I posted the question, I started trying to solve the equation, but you answered so quickly I didn't need to. Is there anything more to be learned from this little experiment?